# What does it mean to break user space?

Tags: linux, kernel

This may be a simple question but, I heard that the only rule in working on the kernel is that you don't break "user space". So I was wondering what that means: *To break user space* and how does it happen?

*Edit*

It has been pointed out to me that this question is not suited for Stack Over Flow by @lurker so I will move it to Super User as @lurker suggests. (See below)

*"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User." – lurker, jww, SilentKiller*

Comment: Did you ever post it on superuser? i can't find it.

Comment: @amenthes no I haven't, feel free to. If you do so, could you please link it below.

Comment: This question should have gone to "Software Engineering", not super user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're referring to Linus Torvald's first rule of kernel development. This note explains it: https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/12/23/75. *I.e.*, when maintaining the kernel, do not do something which breaks user programs/applications. In other words, when making kernel changes, it is very bad to cause problems in the user's application "space". That doesn't literally mean memory. That means anything that impacts the user applications in a way that negatively affects its behavior (causes the program to malfunction). The note I cite also indicates at least one example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's still not what I am looking for. Linus Torvalds mentions it a few times. My question is: what is breaking user space, what is user space and when does it happen. Your link although relevant does not help answer my question.

Comment: @Warosaurus I think I did answer it: user space is the user program/ application space (versus the kernel space). I've clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: Your initial answer was extremely vague but after clarifying your answer, does it help. I had no idea this question was not suited for Stack Over Flow so I will instead ask this question on Super User for a more in depth answer. Thank you.

Comment: That lkml link is gold, thanks!