# Delete a file in Linux assembly x86

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, delete-file

I'm trying to write an assembly program for Linux assembly x86 that erases a file from a directory. Any tips?

Comment: You need to invoke the `unlink` system call, or the similarly named function from from libc, or the `remove` function from libc. Not sure why you couldn't find that information...

Comment: Search 'system calls in linux assembly' or some such, it's easy to find.

Comment: Or create a simple C program that calls `unlink`, compile it with `gcc -S`, and look at the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
    .section .data
    fpath:
        .asciz "/home/user/filename"  # path to file to delete

    .section .text
    .globl _start
    _start:
    movl $10, %eax       # unlink syscall 
    movl $fpath, %ebx    # path to file to delete
    int  $0x80 

    movl %eax, %ebx      # put syscall ret value in ebx
    movl $1, %eax        # exit syscall
    int  $0x80
```

then check the return value at the command line, 0 being success.

```
    $>echo $?
```

I tried this code and it would not unlink a file if invoked from the same
directory as the file to delete, it would unlink files from other dirs.
This is 32 bit code so on a 64 bit os if your source file was un-link.s,
you would need to create the executable with:

```
    $> as --32 -gdwarf2 un-link.s -o un-link.o
```

leave out the -gdwarf2 if you don't need to run it with gdb debugger,
then link with:

```
    $> ld -m elf_i386 un-link.o -o un-link
```

hope it works for you

Comment: *I tried this code and it would not unlink a file if invoked from the same directory as the file to delete, it would unlink files from other dirs*.  Your example always calls [`unlink("/home/user/filename")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html), which is an absolute path so of course it does the same thing regardless of what the current directory is.  If you want it to use a relative path, you can `unlink("filename")`.  Use `strace` to see what system calls you're making.

Answer (score 2):

I see alot of people using `int 0x80` for this, this is deprecated and for most things, you should not use it because it is extremely slow and is subject to possible removal at any point in future. The only cases where you should use `int 0x80` would be in a case where space saving is much more important than speed or where sysenter is not supported on the target platform (pre-Pentium 4 CPUs).

In x86 Linux syscalls work by having the syscall code in eax and any arguments for it in the successive registers, ebx, ecx etc. The return value of the syscall will be placed in eax.

```
mov eax, 0xa ;0xa is the 'unlink' syscall, which removes a file
mov ebx, <location in memory of a null terminated string containing a path>
push <LABEL TO JUMP TO AFTER SYSENTER IS COMPLETE>
push ecx
push edx
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sysenter
```

If you don't care about your registers being filled with garbage after the syscall finishes (such as in cases where you'll be overwriting the contents of those registers immediately anyway) you can use this trick to save some space and speed things up a little:

```
mov eax, 0xa ;0xa is the 'unlink' syscall, which removes a file
mov ebx, <location in memory of a null terminated string containing a path>
push <LABEL TO JUMP TO AFTER SYSENTER IS COMPLETE>
lea ebp, [esp-12]
sysenter
```

Comment: [Linux has a strict don't-break-userspace policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954270/what-does-it-mean-to-break-user-space).  There's pretty much zero change that `int 0x80` will ever go away, unless you leave out support for the 32-bit ABI altogether (in an x86-64 kernel).  Also worth mentioning that 32-bit glibc uses sysenter via the kernels VDSO page, so you might want to suggest calling that sysenter wrapper exported by the kernel.

Comment: I think you have a bug in your second block: the value LEA puts into EBP is overwritten without being used.

Comment: Really the best suggestion is to write 64-bit code and use the `syscall` instruction (with different registers for arg-passing and different syscall numbers.  See [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for ABI docs).  `syscall` doesn't require a complicated dance between user-space and the kernel, it's a lot like `int 0x80` so it's easy for beginners.  32-bit x86 is mostly obsolete (esp. on Linux where there's no efficient register-args/non-x87 32-bit ABI), so I'd consider coding 32-bit `sysenter` to be more of a "fun fact" than something generally useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I did make a mistake, I've corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks.  So EBP holds the new-ESP value, and `sysenter` will return user-space with ESP = the value from EBP?  Neat.  The x86-64 `syscall` ABI doesn't have the kernel look at the user-space stack at all (unless you pass a pointer to stack space, of course).

Comment: Note that direct use of `sysenter` by user-space is discouraged; that ABI is *not* guaranteed stable.  It has apparently changed once in the past, and the only future-proof supported way to make fast 32-bit system calls is by calling into the VDSO.  But for toy experiments manual `sysenter` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write assembly code that erases a file from a directory, you can use multiple methods, but one of the best ways is to use the linux systemcall 'unlink'. In order to have to use the proper system call, you have to figure out if you have an x86 system, or an x86-64 system, or any other kind of system. I will specify how to do this using only x86/x86-64. 
 
So system calls work as following in linux: 
1. 
You put a number into return register (eax or rax depending on system) that corresponds to a system call's number, like `$1` is sys_exit on x86 and `$29` is sys_pause, you have to make sure you get the right number in %eax or it won't work. (I feel the need to emphasize this, this number is SYSTEM DEPENDENT, so an x86 syscall number in %eax will not do the same thing in an x86-64 system). Also, OS's may tamper with this as well, I will only talk about linux, I can't speak for any other OS.

2.
Then you move the arguments into the proper registers that is specified BY THE SYSTEM, again, find a reference for your specific system, and you will know which registers to put your arguments for the function into (some syscalls don't need arguments, so this step is unnecessary, why would you need an argument for sys_exit, idk).
 
3.
Then finally you use syscall for your system to let the system know to run a specific function (the one you specified by putting a number into %eax/%rax). 
 
Let's look at an example of some assembly code that deletes a file in two different systems, x86, and x86-64 (windows has its own method, but I will not talk about that one, although it does exist). If I wanted to delete/unlink the file stored at address 0x7fff50 (let's say you don't want to specify fpath and you know the address)
In x86:

```
movl $10, %eax        # defines which systemcall we are using (10th)
movl $0x7fff50, %ebx  # moves the address of file we want to delete into %ebx (this is where the argument of sys_unlink(x86) is stored)
int  $0x80            # equivalent of syscall that starts the appropriate function
```

In x86-64:

```
movq $87, %rax        # defines which systemcall we are using (87th)
movq $0x7fff50, %rdi  # moves the address of file we want to delete into %rdi (this is where the argument of sys_unlink(x86-64) is stored)
syscall               # starts the appropriate function
```

If you are more of a normal person and don't know the absolute address of the file you are trying to delete, we have an easy way to write relative addresses of the file itself, like so (as copied from the other answer)
    `.section .data`
    `fpath:`
        `.asciz "/home/user/filename"  # path to file to delete`

then the system itself will figure out where the absolute path (something like 7fff34fb) to the file is, and move that into the register when you compile the assembly. Might look like this

In x86-64:

```
.section .data
fpath:
    .asciz "/home/user/filename"  # path to file to delete

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movq $87, %rax        # defines which systemcall we are using (87th)
movq $fpath, %rdi     # moves the address of file we want to delete into %rdi
                      # (this is where the argument of sys_unlink(x86-64) is stored)
syscall               # starts the appropriate function
```

You can access the output of the function (usually 0 for success or 1 for fail status) by looking at the `%eax` register. After each syscall, an integer is returned in `%eax`

You can put this text into a text file 'program.s' (I would suggest using notepad/notepad++, '.s' stands for assembly code) and compile it using gcc with `$ gcc -c program.s` to get the object code, and you can print and look at the object code and the hex keys involved with each command using `$ objdump -d program.o` 
For more information about how to look up which syscall is which number and which register to put the arguements in, go here:
For x86-64: https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/

Comment: An immediate absolute address is a really weird choice for an example.  On x86-64, the function calling convention is nearly the same as the syscall calling convention, so it might already be in rdi.  Otherwise I'd suggest the usual static storage that asm newbie examples use, so `mov  $path_buffer, %rdi` or `mov path_pointer, %rdi`

Comment: edited to add more useful versions

Comment: I think you should just take out the weird version, instead of showing it first and then giving the normal way.